# PHP cannot access variable declared in loaded php page with jquery load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Usually I can get php variables from a different php file declared like this:

```
$myVar = 'hello';
require 'header.php'
```

So then in header.php I can use $myVar. But I cannot access a variable that I loaded with ajax in jquery. For example:

index.php:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div id="myDiv"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

In a script I have:

```
$(#myDiv).load('newPage.php')
```

newPage.php :

$myLoadedVar = 'loaded var';

But then I cannot access $myLoadedVar from index.php, is it possible to do this or you cannot access php variables created with ajax ?

Comment: yeah that's not how it works, you could echo out something that will populate the div but you can not access php variables in this manner.

Comment: No, you cannot "create PHP variables" in JavaScript...

Comment: @JimmyB Well, my intention is not to create variables. I am using ajax to fill dynamically a list with values from DB. The thing is that I use a query and save the values in a php variable. And I want to use that variable later so I don't have to query again the DB. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language while JavaScript is a client-side language.  The only way you can get PHP data into JavaScript is by outputting the data in some manner.  If you want the full output, just echo it.  If you want to load a bunch of simple PHP variables into JavaScript, you can add all the variables you need JS to know about into an array, and then `json_encode` them.

```
$firstName = 'John';
$lastName = 'Doe';
$outputArray = array('firstName' => $firstName, 'lastName' => $lastName);
echo json_encode($outputArray);
```

Then when an ajax function can retrieve this data as an object and you can use `result.firstName` in JavaScript.

Passing complex items is impossible though, such as those with database connections as properties.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I am just using ajax to load a php file, and I want to use a variable defined in the loaded php file in the php file using the ajax, I don't want to use it for JS.

Comment: When you say load, you hoping to load the PHP code right with the AJAX call? As rannmann stated this isn't possible.  What is happening is the AJAX call is loading the rendered bits from the PHP (assuming you are rendering something, ie: echo statement or maybe mixin of html code...).  In other words you can't access the defined variable in the PHP file via AJAX at least in the form that you are asking.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes more sense, so AJAX will only output the echo parts of the php file it is loading and all the variables and everything else will be lost after finishing loading  ?

Comment: Yes.  Once PHP has finished running and rendered the result, the PHP variables cease to exist.